# Can I receive to myetherwallet.com with this code any ETH?

Tags: transactions

Can I actually receive ETH to my MyEtherWAllet.com account
with this token contract source?

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa1ccc166faf0e998b3e33225a1a0301b1c86119d#code

Or do I have set token-name and symbol and other things?

If I have to set symbol, token-name and so on, where to edit this contract code, please?

Comment: You have no function with the payable modifier, that contract cannot receive ether. If you are creating an ERC20 token it is better to use the [EIP20 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md), if you are not then you do not need the `name` and `symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you deployed smart contract, you can't modify the source code of contract. You can setup your token name and symbol by using `SetupToken` function.

In your contract you don't have any `payable` fallback function or function with `payable` modifier.

```
contract Token {

    string public symbol = "token";
    string public name = "tkn";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 _totalSupply = 0;

    event Received(address _from, uint256 amount);

    function Token(uint256 _supply){
        _totalSupply =  _supply;
    }

    function () payable {
        Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, although this doesnt answer 100% my question. Anyway: Thank you, I appreciate. My question still is: Can I receive ETH to that smart contract?

Comment: is this solution works for you?

Comment: You wasnt 100% right, because the contract souce code doesnt show the values in their raw version, but as you can see at the link I sent you, there are symbol, name and decimals already filled and it works. So I can send to any ETH address. BTW: You can have some token, because you took care. Simply send me your ETH address and I will compensate you with some SGELDER coin. The balance you can check by adding a token to your Ether wallet the following way:  tokenaddress: see link above, symbol: SGEL, decimals: 18

Comment: Thanks, my ether address is `0x4DBA298F414EefA6430CfBCc051c4956DFb6f60C`.

Comment: Will be sent within 24 hours

Comment: I just sent you a small amount of SGEL

Comment: You can see it here:https://ethplorer.io/address/0xa1ccc166faf0e998b3e33225a1a0301b1c86119d#tab=tab-holders